# Sending Mulitple Variable from Javascript to PHP page using $.post

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to send 4 variables for a pagination page but am getting stuck in sending them.
Would someone be so kind as to explain for me.

```
$('input#Query_Submit').on('click', function() {
    var PartNumber = $('input#Query').val();
        $("#Loading").show();
        ShowLoading = true;
    if ($.trim(PartNumber ) != ''){
        $.post('small-displays/Results.php', {
            Query: PartNumber ,
            pn: pn,
            last: last,
            rpp: rpp,
            }, function(data) {
        ShowLoading = false;

        $("#Loading").hide();
            $('div#Results-Data').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

I think I'm using the wrong syntax to pass the variables?

Many Thanks in advance!

EDIT-  UPDATED MY VARIABLE NAMES AND TYPO'S
In my haste I have mis-spelled and used incorrect variables - CORRECTED

Comment: The only *obvious* problem here is that you don't appear to have defined any of the variables.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Nothing showing up which is what's completely stumped me...  Gonna delete it off the server and re-upload the file incase it's not over writing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so answer it is.

Clarifications:

- Are you sure that you pass this condition ($.trim(Query) != '') ?
- Are you sure that all the variables are not undefined?

Also check the console if there are errors or add some console.log() like this

```
$.post('small-displays/Results.ph', {
      Query: Query,
      pn: pn,
      last: last,
      rpp: rpp,
},function(data) {

      ShowLoading = false;
      $("#Loading").hide();
      $('div#Resulsts-Data').html(data);

}).fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi YeahBoy, thanks for your answer, I managed to resolve this by some unknown white space or server lag issue.  Even more confused than before! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Ok not sure why, how or what the ....

I deleted it off the server and returned the same zero results...

I then got thinking on whitespaces...

For some, i have no idea reason, i changed a whitespace seperator :->

```
Query: PartNumber ,

Query: PartNumber,
```

And voila! I think it may be down to some other reason, server lag, upload lag, download lag or some other variation of issue, but it's working lol